# How do I share MenuItems between a ContextMenu and a ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, contextmenu

I have a context menu attached to a panel, that should mirror commands available in a toolbar menu.

Currently in my `MouseUp` event, I set the `enabled` state of the `MenuItem`s, and add them to the context menu:

```
    ctxMnuLinks.Items.Clear()
    ctxMnuLinks.Items.Add(mnuLinksOpen)
    ctxMnuLinks.Items.Add(New ToolStripSeparator)
    ctxMnuLinks.Items.Add(mnuLinksAdd)
    ctxMnuLinks.Items.Add(mnuLinksEdit)
    ctxMnuLinks.Items.Add(New ToolStripSeparator)
    ...
```

..but this removes the items from the toolbar menu! So obviously I can't use the same object.
I would like to avoid duplicating the menu, which would leave me 2 sets of menu items to maintain.

What is the proper way to achieve this? I'm looking for a '*best practice*' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can have the same object in both the toolstrip and context menu, but they can both call the same function in their OnClick event.